# lxc sharing network namespace between containers

Tags: linux, networking, containers, lxc, linux-namespaces

I am trying to start a lxc container deb1 and use `--share-net` to start another container deb2 to share the network namespace. But both in fedora and Ubuntu i and getting error below:

```
issue |

[root@blr-vxr-056 ~]# lxc-start --share-net deb1 -n deb2
lxc-start: cgfs.c: handle_cgroup_settings: 2077 Device or resource busy - failed to set memory.use_hierarchy to 1; continuing
lxc-start: cgfs.c: handle_cgroup_settings: 2077 Device or resource busy - failed to set memory.use_hierarchy to 1; continuing
lxc-start: sync.c: __sync_wake: 62 sync wake failure : Broken pipe
lxc-start: start.c: __lxc_start: 1080 failed to spawn 'deb2'
```

Anyone used `--share-net` option ?